# How to space buttons from the center of the screen evenly in a column with kivymd

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am new to kivy/kivymd and I struggle a lot with positioning buttons (or any other widget) within the screen. Somehow, I find it not intuitive. To get a better feeling, I am working through several small exercises, which I want to solve.

Right now, I want to solve following exercise:

[image: How the screen should look like]

I could use the relative layout, but I hoped I could use a box layout/grid layout instead. I want to "dynamically" add a new button. The spacing to the top and bottom should however be fairly similar. If I try the box layout, the buttons are all on the bottom. Even if I change the complete position of the layout (which wasn't well documented either ...).

E.g.:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    pos: 0,root.height-(root.height*0.5)

    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "button 1"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}


    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "button 2"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}


    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "button 3"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
        

    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "button 4"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
```

Leads to following screen:

[image]

Button 4 sits "on the center" of the screen. However, the center between button 2 and 3 should be at the center of the screen.

Is there an easy way to solve this? Or do I need to calculate the position of all the buttons and assign them via the relative layout?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use properties of the `MDBoxLayout` to get what you want. The `spacing` sets the space between the `Buttons`. The `adaptive_height` allows the `MDBoxLayout` to grow to fit all the `Buttons`. And the `pos_hint` ensures that the `MDBoxLayout` is centered vertically:

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    pos_hint: {'center_y':0.5}
    adaptive_height: True
    spacing: 20
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later on. Do you have any good resources, where I can find exactly this information? The official documentation is ... fine enough ... however exactly the information about positioning and sizing would be good. Like, the API doc doesn't tell what position can be set with a layout.

Comment: The KivyMD documentation is not complete. You must also refer to the [kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.html). So to see all the capabilities of the `MDBoxLayout` you must consult the KivyMD documentation for MDBoxLayout as well as the Kivy documentation for `BoxLayout`.

Comment: Thanks again! I just tried your solution and it works like a charm!